# (Python) Removing quotation marks from called string in input

Tags: python

```
text = "Please enter your weight in", Measurement_system
weight = input(text)
```

I want to give the user a prompt for their input without it being enclosed in quotation marks

In response to the above code it displays:

```
('Please enter your weight in', 'imperial')
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of these quotation marks?
Thanks :)

Comment: `text` is a `tuple` here.You can create an actual string by using `+` or string formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `text` value is actually a tuple because you used a comma during assignment of `text`. Instead, concatenate the strings.

```
text = "Please enter your weight in " + Measurement_system
weight = input(text)
```

Or you could use string formatting (although it's a little overkill in this situation IMO):

```
text = "Please enter your weight in {}".format(Measurement_system)
weight = input(text)
```

Or, the older string formatting syntax

```
text = "Please enter your weight in %s" % Measurement_system
weight = input(text)
```