# How do I include integers in a string in Python?

Tags: python

```
import random


q = random.randint(10, 100)
w = random.randint(10, 100)
e = (q, " * ", w)
r = int(input(e))
```

This outputs (i.e):

```
>>> (60, ' * ', 24)
```

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666310/python-removing-quotation-marks-from-called-string-in-input) post but I faced an error.

I want output to atleast look like:

```
>>> (60 * 24)
```

What I tried was doing

```
import random


q = random.randint(10, 100)
w = random.randint(10, 100)
**e = (q + " * " + w)**
r = int(input(e))
```

Which gave me the error.

Comment: `which gave me the error` What error? Please post the error text so we know what you mean. And does your code actually have the 2 stars at the beginning and end of the line like you have in the second example?

Comment: the problem is that you're trying to add an integer, a string and another integer together, which only works in javascript. What I think you want to do is either use fstrings, as suggested by Barnaby in his answer, or to convert the values into a string first with something like `str(q)` and `str(w)` before adding them together

Comment: @user99999 Yes, my bad. It was a dumb mistake and is solved now. And no I was trying to highlight the part I changed so it would be more obvious but it didn't work probably because it was already in code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format numbers to strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617/format-numbers-to-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great way to do this is with [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

```
e = f"{q} * {w}"
```

You just need to start your string with an f, then include any variables in curly braces `{}`

Answer (score 2):

Your value `e` has mixed types. `q` and `w` are ints while the string is a string. Python prints the types in the tuple as their types. Those quotation marks are not *in* the values they see, they are a built-in helper in python's display

You will need to coerce all three into the same type to do something with them, eg

```
>>> eval(str(q) + ' * ' + str(w))
1482
```

That's the low level pointer, but higher level I need to ask, what are you trying to do?

Comment: This will get the job done here, but please be very careful when using eval. It can become a very sneaky security issue.

Comment: @JovanVuchkov this seems to be a safe case since the variables are just numbers created by the program. Anyway, I think `eval` is used here just to show that they can be operated as strings... maybe not the most intuitive example.

Comment: yeah I'd never encourage using eval in a program with user defined input. This is demonstrative of types while it's unclear what TC wants to do.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @TristanBodding-Long ! I'm trying to make an app with randomized math problems.